# Some files are not openable in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse

For unknown reason, files of some types become not open-able in Eclipse IDE, for examples, *.txt, *.am, *.mak. When i right-click on files of those types in Project Explorer view, there is no "Open" or "Open With" menu options shown up like *.cc and *.hh. Those files types were use to be open-able within the same projects.

I confirm that the unopenable file types are associated with respective editors.

What may be wrong with my project or workspace settings?

[2013-09-30-update]
Still find no clue on why all non-c/c++ files cannot be opened by Eclipse IDE running on my Macbook :(

I imported the directories containing the files to create a project on Eclipse. The directories are mounted via Samba.

Any answer will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Go to windows > preferences > general tab > editors > file associations and check your file type if its not present add them. It will be done.

Comment: thanks. but i confirm that those unopenable files types are present and ARE ASSOCIATED with default editor (eg. text editor or Makefile editor)

Comment: If you right-click the file in the Package Explorer/Navigator, you will see an Open-With menu item where you can select how the file should be opened. So, if you need to edit an `.mak` file just right-click and select `Open With > your_required_editor`. There is also the `Other...` submenu item where you could pick other modes for Eclipse to open the file.

Comment: thanks again. Unfortunately, for those unopenable files, right-clicking the files does NOT see OPEN or OPEN-WITH menu item.